# Selecting json data in JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json

**i have an ajax form  and the response data is this json**

```
[{"runtime":"142 min" , "title":"blabla"}]
```

but when i see it from chrome developer tools it is like this

```
[Object]
0: Object
runtime: "142 min"
title: "blabla"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

if i want to set one of the keys to a var what should i do

i tried **`var x = data.runtime ;`** but it isnt working

i tried **`var x = data.0.runtime ;`**
and it makes a syntax error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the square brackets around your JSON data - it's not an object, but an *array*, containing one value - your object.

To access that object, [access the first value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in the array: `data[0].runtime`.